# How to pass data from html form to php controller

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone help me with this one because I'm stuck. I have simple form in my header like this :

```js
<form name="search" action="Home\search" method="post">
            Search: <input type="text" name="term" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
```

My model function is like:

```js
public function search(string $term)
    {
        $statement = self::$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.title  LIKE ? ".
        "OR posts.content LIKE ?");
        $string = '%'. $term .'%';
        $statement->bind_param("ss", $string, $string);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $result;
    }
```

and the controller:

```js
    public function search()
    {
        $str = $_POST['term'];
        if (count($this->model->search($str)) > 0){
            $this->redirect('home', 'search');
        }
        else{
            $this->addErrorMessage("Cannot find any results");
        }
    }
```

The error i have is: "Undefined index: term in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\blog\controllers\HomeController.php"

I can see that the problem is passing the data from form to the controller, but u can't understand why. Thanks for your time.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I got that, thanks.